# Como reconfigurar arquivos de inicialização do eclipse, quando não se pode abri-lo?

Tags: eclipse, atualização

Eu recebi um lembrete que havia uma atualização para eclipse. Mandei baixar e instalar as atualizações. Ao final o eclipse pediu para reiniciar o mesmo. Permiti que o eclipse fosse reiniciado. Até ai nada de errado.

Contudo, o eclipse agora não inicia mais. Quando clico no ícone do eclipse ele até começa a abrir mas fica só no retângulo de abertura piscando.

A opção de reinstalar o eclipse está fora de cogitação. Tive MESES de trabalho pra conseguir instalar o xdebug no eclipse, e sua configuração sempre me da dor de cabeça.

Eu pretendo:

1) Encontrar a pasta onde encontra-se os arquivos de configuração do eclipse;
2) Acessar os arquivos corretos onde posso desfazer a atualização que deu errado. Voltando o mesmo para o perfeito estado anterior a atualização.

Não sei onde mexer exatamente para fazer essas correções. Eu sei os arquivos que foram alterados no dia do ocorrido, são eles:

- config.ini
- org.eclipse.osgi
- .settings
- org.eclipse.oomph.setup
- org.eclipse.update

config.ini

```
#This configuration file was written by:                                         org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
#Mon Mar 06 16:23:09 BRT 2017
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.php
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.2.v20161107-1947.jar
equinox.use.ds=true eclipse.buildId=4.6.2.M201611241400osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.
equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.200.v20160504-1450.jar@1\:startorg.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.infoeclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ideosgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platformosgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.200.v20160504-1419.jar,reference\:file\:javax.transaction_1.1.1.v201105210645.jar,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension_1.0.2.v201610280128.jar osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4 eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
```

.settings/org.jboss.tools.usage.prefs

```
allow_usage_report_preference=false
ask_user_for_usage_report_preference=false
eclipse.preferences.version=1
first_visit=1484161201009
last_visit=1488824889259
visit_count=168
```

Alguém nesse fórum com certeza já passou por isso e resolveu direto nas pastas do programa. é isso que eu quero.
Não quero ter que reinstalar tudo sempre que ocorre um erro grave.

A VERDADEIRA SOLUÇÃO PASSA LONGE DE "REINSTALAR" UM PROGRAMA!

Comment: No arquivo de log na pasta do eclipse ele mostra algum erro especifico?

Comment: Dei uma procuradas nas pastas (linux) do eclipse e não achei o arquivo de log, onde deve estar no linux?

Comment: Na pasta do workspace não tem um arquivo `.log`?

Comment: achei arquivos como este hs_err_pid2366.log mas nenhum da data em questão nem de hoje. Eles estão na pasta eclipse mesmo. Contudo, o verdadeiro workspace fica em lampp/htdocs onde coloco meus projetos. E lá não há arquivos de log. Vou ver se o eclipse os coloca em outro lugar agora.

Comment: No workspace/.metadata tem algum arquivo de hoje?

Comment: Tenho dois workspaces. Um chamado worksapce que guarda os projetos javaSE/EE e nesse lugar achei um log dentro da pasta .metadata mas é de um mes atraz e relata sobre uma SESSAO. EU simplesmente não acho esse arquivo. vou pesquisar no pc tudo com a extensão .log pra ver se acho.

Comment: achei dentro do .metadata dentro do htdocs. Consta nele o seguinte varas entradas de : !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse 4 0 2017-03-06 16:13:45.733
!MESSAGE Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /home/fabiano/Downloads/eclipse/features/org.eclipse.jsf_sdk.feature_3.9.0.v201609161615.jar.

Comment: Deve ter omeçado o problema com esse equinox.p2 o que é isso? vi o começo do log assim: !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 4 1006 2017-03-04 18:33:53.183
!MESSAGE Unknown Host: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20150821153341/repository/content.xml
!STACK 0
java.net.UnknownHostException: download.eclipse.org
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)

Comment: consegui abrir o eclipse indo na pasta ../eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/ .manager e apagando os arquivos .filetable que tem lá. ai abriu o eclipse de novo.